# Mysql 5.6 column on update current timestamp not working in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have  a column called lastModified in the table answer, something like following

```
 +--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
 | Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
 +--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
 | answerId     | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
 | totalComment | int(11)        | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
 | totalView    | int(11)        | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
 | totalSpam    | int(11)        | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
 | lastModified | timestamp      | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
 +--------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Whenever I manullay update to any one of totalComment, totalView, totalSpam columns in mysql console the lastModifed column also get modified with current timestamp. But when I am doing the same thing with hibernate application it is not getting modified.

My application is implemented as part of spring data jpa. In application.yml I tried using both **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect** and **org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect** but no help.

In my annotated Answer entity class lastModified column is declared as following

```
@Column
private Date lastModified;

public Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
}

public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
}
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are _any_ of the changes to columns being persisted to the database using Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, but not the current timestamp value of lastModified.

Comment: If lastmodified field is a timestamp that will be set to the furrent time if the record is changed, then you should not be updating it manually, only retrieve its value. Mysql will update this field if you modify a record.

Comment: I am not updating lastModified column, I am updating other than lastmodified column like totalComment or toatalView then mysql update this field for a modified reord, which is fine in mysql console but the same activities doesn't work in hibernate application, I mean I don't see the updated lastModified value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the @Shadow mentioned, your current schema design implies that you want MySQL to automatically set the `lastModified` field for you (`on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).  So if you pass `null` from your Java code, then it should work as expected.  Try using the `updatable = false` option in your column definition to tell JPA not to send a value to MySQL:

```
@Column(name = "lastModified",
        updatable = false)
private Date lastModified;
```

My guess as to what is currently happening is that Hibernate is populating the `lastModified` field with the value from the database, and then your JPA code is then persisting this *same* value back to MySQL.  So it appears that the value is not being updated.  But what is really happening is that your JPA code *is* doing an update with the same old value.

Comment: Hmm, I got your point. Its working as expected now. Thanks @Tim .